# SDL crashes when any standard variable is declared

Tags: c, crash, sdl, sdl-2

This SDL program works fine (displays a windows and a draws a bitmap onto it), however, if I declare any variables in my program (such as int, long, etc), the windows freezes and is white instead of black and nothing draws. What could possibly cause this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // line below will cause SDL crash
    // int blabla = 640; 
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "A rather exceptional SDL window",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640,
        480,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
    );
    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Texture *texture;
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_Surface *brush;
    brush = IMG_Load("brush2.png");
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, brush);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_Rect *sRect, *dRect;
    sRect->w = 10;
    sRect->h = 4;
    sRect->x = 0;
    sRect->y = 0;
    dRect->w = 10;
    dRect->h = 4;
    dRect->x = 10;
    dRect->y = 10;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, sRect, dRect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(1000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you declared that variable?

Comment: @rullof See the commented out line "int blabla = 640" - yes, _indeed_, if that unrelated variable (or any unrelated variable) is declared, SDL will freeze and not draw. It will compile fine and there would be no issues if there were no SDL code, but for some reason, SDL freezes if I try to define any unrelated standard variable, such as the commented out line.

Comment: In other words, since "int blabla = 640" is commented out, the code you see above compiles fine. If you un-comment "int blabla = 640" or write "int bob = 44" or "long joe = 34", it will compile fine of course, but _SDL will freeze_ and not draw. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are writing unallocated memory.

```
SDL_Rect *sRect, *dRect;
sRect->w = 10; /* w doesn't exist. Writing is undefined behaviour. */
```

`sRect` and `dRect` are only pointers. They need to point to valid memory before struct members are accessed.

You could declare them in stack instead:

```
SDL_Rect sRect, dRect;
sRect.w = 10;
sRect.h = 4;
...
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, &sRect, &dRect);
```

You should also check return values of `SDL_`-functions. If those fail, and you continue execution regardless, you may experience weird behaviour or crashes.

Comment: Those lines do not cause errors - SDL asks for pointers and that code works. It's simply declaring a variable (any variable, unrelated to SDL -- _unrelated_ is the key part) that causes SDL to freeze. See the commented out line "int blabla = 640" If I uncomment that line, or declare ANY variable, SDL will freeze. If I do _not_ declare any variables, everything works fine and SDL draws on screen. What could one possibly have to do with the other? The "blabla" variable isn't even used in the program and doesn't cause any errors - why would SDL freeze when an unrelated variable is declared?

Comment: `sRect->w = 10;` writes to unallocated area. That will cause undefined behaviour. This means that **anything** can happen. It may work, it may not work, it may crash for totally unrelated reason. Declaring variable `blabla` most likely changes position of `sRect` on stack, which means that initial (garbage) value of the pointer is different. It working in the first place was pure luck.

Comment: Thanks - your solution did fix it. I still don't understand why C would let you write to unallocated areas (then what's the point of allocation?) and how this means "anything can happen" (e.g. even if the unallocated area is the "blabla" var, it still shouldn't affect SDL as the variable is never access by SDL or anything after that point. But it works, so thanks again, I'll move on.